# Azure Entra External ID

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

By default the sign-in url and query string is really long and this seems unnecessary:

```
https://company.b2clogin.com/company.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_sign_in&client_id=12345678-123a-12ab-1aa2-12341234&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

Is it possible to somehow reduce this to:

```
    https://company.b2clogin.com/login
```

Or at least:

```
    https://company.b2clogin.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

I'd like to make the URL as straightforward as possible for our users

Answer (score 0):

Parameters such as client_id, scope and redirect_url are required by the OIDC spec.

The "p" (policy) parameter is used to define the B2C policy to use.

So they can't be removed otherwise you will get an e.g. missing client_id error message.